# Is it safe to use window.parent.myFunction in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

In the JavaScript for the `<iframe>` I need to call a function in the parent window. Both windows are from the same domain.

Is it safe to use `window.parent.myFunction();`?

Comment: my two concerns are 1. different versions of browsers providing access to the function in different ways. window.parent.myFun, window.parentWindow.myFunc. 2. Security settings blocking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, you can use `window.parent` from the same domain.

The [WhatWG specification chapter 6: Loading Web pages](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html) says:

- `iframe.parent` exists
- `iframe.parent` is a proxy to the DOM of the `iframe`'s parent
- Access is allowed if the origins are the same

## Really long, long answer

I am trying to show you how you can come to this conclusion by reading the specification, while keeping in the mind: *What are the characteristic traits of accessing `parent` from within an `iframe`?*

Let's start. It's a long text.

### 1. DOM attribute `parent`

[WhatWG#dom-parent](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#dom-parent) says about `window.parent`:

> The parent IDL attribute on the `Window` object of a `Document` in a browsing context *b* must return the `WindowProxy` object of the parent *browsing context*, if there is one (i.e. if *b* is a child browsing context), or the `WindowProxy` object of the browsing context *b* itself, otherwise (i.e. if it is a top-level browsing context or a detached nested browsing context).

`parent` is an attribute to access something like the DOM of the parent window. However:

- What is a *browsing context*?
- What does `WindowProxy` do?

Let's continue reading.

### 2. Browsing context

A browsing context is an environment in which `Document` objects are presented to the user.

[WhatWG#Browsing context](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#windows) says:

> A tab or window in a Web browser typically contains a browsing context, as does an iframe or frames in a frameset. Each browsing context has a corresponding WindowProxy object.

### 3. Window proxy

The window proxy is an object to proxy a `window` object and to enforce, for example, security constraints. For a `window` object there can be several proxies (for example two `iframes` from two different domains accessing the same parent).

[WhatWG#proxy-object](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#the-windowproxy-object) says:

> The WindowProxy object allows scripts to act as if each browsing context had a single Window object, while still keeping separate Window objects for each Document.

### 4. Security

We are almost there. Keep reading.

[WhatWG#security-nav](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#security-nav) says:

> A browsing context A is allowed to navigate a second browsing context B if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - Either the origin of the active document of A is the same as the origin of the active document of B, or
>
>   The browsing context A is a nested browsing context with a top-level browsing context, and its top-level browsing context is B, or
>
>   The browsing context B is an auxiliary browsing context and A is allowed to navigate B's opener browsing context, or
>
>   The browsing context B is not a top-level browsing context, but there exists an ancestor browsing context of B whose active document has the same origin as the active document of A (possibly in fact being A itself).

### 5. Deduction

Can an `iframe` access functions from its `parent`, if both are from the same domain? Lets deduce.

1. `parent` is not the `window` object of the parent, but a `WindowProxy`.
2. The *browsing context* of the `iframe` can access its parent, because they both have the same origin (see the first security condition above).

You see: If you read a specification carefully, you can find answers how browsers should behave. Reading specifications is an acquired skill. It needs patience and exactness.

However: The world is not so nice. There are browsers which do not implement specifications as well as they should. *Caveat emptor*.